# Can a wrapper variable within a Singleton object get garbage collected while Singleton is not null?

Tags: java, android, null, garbage-collection, wrapper

In this Singleton instance, can this `private Long severDate` become garbage collected when the singleton instance is still not null?

I encountered this is in an Android app. Wondering Android OS somehow freeing unused individual memory values.

```
public class DataHolder {

    private static DataHolder self;

    private Long severDate; 
    private int numb;

    public static synchronized DataHolder getInstance() {
            if (self == null) {
                self = new DataHolder();
            }
            return self;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Since the memory reserved by an instance of `DataHolder` contains a reference to a `Long` object, the reference's memory could not be free until the memory allocated to the  `self` gets free.

Comment: And that is the entire code? `serverDate` is _never_ used?

Comment: @aminography this Long value is used rarely compared to other variables. Sometimes, users can let the Android app go background about 1/2hr and use it again. I suspect during that time probably the entire DataHolder object may get garbage collected. However, I still cannot prove that. Just wondering whether Android memory optimization can release memory from individual variables prior to that.

Comment: @Eugene not never used, it is used only when users place orders. But DataHolder references are being used everywhere in the app. Only the getter of this serverDate might not use that frequently. Also, according to logic, there is no way this value get null value after the initial assign , I never modify the value again . I had already confirmed that.

Comment: @virtualpathum and I have already confirmed that ( unless Android does something weird with the lifecycle of this Object) there is not really a way for this to be GCed. You will not get a different answer.

Comment: @Eugene Yeah. Thanks for the support. Will have to dig deeper

Comment: There is a difference between garbage collection and killing (and restarting) an app. In the latter case, the field will be `null` because you didn’t implement persistence for its value (and its initial value is `null`).

Answer (score 0):

Until "Long severDate" has a references to it, GC wont be deleting it. Now it all depends on the useCase whether u have created the instance of this singleton class in some classes or not.
P.S: In android make sure that u create the obj of this class in onCreate method.